# Curious if this chaotic recurrence relation has a name and/or interesting properties

Tags: recurrences, chaos

I was playing around with 2-dimensional recurrence relations and I stumbled upon this:

$$
x_{n+1} = \sin(k(y_n + x_n))\\
y_{n+1} = \sin(k(y_n - x_n))
$$

I was wondering if this was a known recurrence relation and if it might have any interesting properties. I posted [a question about this on Math StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2654984/identifying-this-chaotic-recurrence-relation) 8 months ago but nobody was able to identify it.

---

#### Additional information

I built an interactive bifurcation diagram which can be viewed here:

http://matt-diamond.com/sineMap.html

Here's the image when the starting coordinates are [0.5, 0.5]

[image: sine map bifurcation diagram]

The bifurcation diagram seems to have two distinct forms, depending on whether or not the starting coordinate is on an axis/diagonal.

Here's an animation starting from an initial state of [0.1, 0.2] and *k* increasing from 0 to 2:

[image]

Same thing but an initial state of [1, 0]:

[image]

Here's some interesting behavior as *k* proceeds from 1 to 1.6:

[image]

Here's *k* = 1.4, $y_0 = 0$, $x_0$ increasing from 0 to 1:

[image]

It's like you can watch it shifting between two different limit cycles...

Comment: I'm curious about the Feigenbaum constant of such a system.